# How to parse JSON data from Digital Ocean API

Tags: json, python-3.x, api, python-requests, digital-ocean

Hello there i am trying to build  a App Out of Digital Ocean API so basically i am sending a request to https://api.digitalocean.com/v2/droplets using the requests library(Python) and here's my code

```
import requests
host = "https://api.digitalocean.com"
headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "Bearer MYTOKEN"
    }
dataa = {}
api = requests.post(f"{host}/v2/droplets", headers= headers, data=json.dumps(dataa))
```

And then try to access  the info returned by API by `data = api.json()`
and if i try to print the id by running `print(data['droplet']['id'])` i running onto this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/gogamic/code/gogamic-website/functions.py", line 276, in <module>
    create_new_server('mai@gogamic.com', 2)
  File "/home/gogamic/code/gogamic-website/functions.py", line 260, in create_new_server
    server_info = json.loads(infoo.json())
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 898, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/__init__.py", line 525, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 370, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 400, in raw_decode
    return self.scan_once(s, idx=_w(s, idx).end())
simplejson.errors.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

This is the returned [JSON](https://controlc.com/16e917cd)  From the API

Comment: Could you try just printing the response body, `print(api.text)`, I would imagine you are getting the error because the response is not a json and `.json()` is trying to convert it into a json even though it is an invalid one.

Comment: it's returning a string but i am not able to loop through it

Comment: hard to say what's wrong without seeing the actual response, might be encoded ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That API method is a `GET` not a `POST`:

https://developers.digitalocean.com/documentation/v2/#list-all-droplets

Your code works for me replacing:

```
api = requests.post(f"{host}/v2/droplets",
                    headers= headers,
                    data=json.dumps(dataa))
```

With:

```
api = requests.get(f"{host}/v2/droplets",
                    headers= headers,
                    data=json.dumps(dataa))
```

And per @fixatd adding:

```
print(api)
```

Yields:

```
<Response [200]>
```

> **NOTE** I have no droplets to list.

For completeness, create a droplet and re-run:

```sh
doctl compute droplet create stackoverflow-65092533 \
--region sfo3 \
--size s-1vcpu-2gb \
--ssh-keys ${KEY} \
--tag-names stackoverflow \
--image ubuntu-20-10-x64
```

Then:

Using:

```
content = resp.json()

if resp.status_code != 200:
    print("Unexpected status code: {}".format(resp.status_code))
    quit()

for droplet in content["droplets"]:
    print("ID: {}\tName: {}".format(droplet["id"], droplet["name"]))
```

Yields:

```
ID: 219375538   Name: stackoverflow-65092533
```